# print preview Editing with user contols

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created  a MS word  document data field(mail merge) values with using MS Excel values to be print.  Each Printing randomly get next Excel row values. Here I want modify at the end of each print that shows print preview and modify only mail merge data field values and other document contents as read only format.

Is There any possible way to do that…

Comment: In print Preview i want to edit only the taken data field(mail merge) value.others contents shows as read only format in the Document.Is there any possible way ?

Comment: Can you share the code that you have written so far?